# How to fix mixed content problem in TYPO3

Tags: typo3, content-management-system, typo3-7.6.x, mixed-content

I have a problem on my website developed with TYPO3. The problem is that CSS files and JavaScript and images not working. So many images and other functionality such as the slider are not working.

This is the first issue: Mixed content: load all resources via HTTPS to improve the security of your site

[image: Mixed content issues]

And this is the other issue: Ensure CORS requesting origin matches resource's allowed origin

[image: Second issues]

Answer (score 2):

The problem is because you have loaded the site through HTTPS protocol and images, CSS and JS files are loaded through HTTP protocol.

You have to set the correct protocol in TypoScript Setup configuration :

```
config.baseURL = https://www.you-site.com/
```

Then all your resources will be loaded through this URL.

I think that the CORS problem will also be solved with this configuration.

Comment: Can you tell me wehre can i add this code on backend please ?

Comment: In your TypoScript Setup: https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-typoscript/main/en-us/Setup/Config/Index.html#baseurl